# What are the good maximal compact subgroups in $p$-adic unitary groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups, buildings

Let $E/\mathbb Q_{p}$ be a quadratic extension and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $E$-hermitian space. Denote the hermitian form by $(\cdot,\cdot):V\times V \rightarrow E$. Let $G := \mathrm{U}(V)$ be the associated unitary group, ie. the group of elements $g\in \mathrm{GL}_E(V)$ such that $(gv,gw) = (v,w)$ for all $v,w\in V$. Then $G$ can be seen as the group of $\mathbb Q_p$-rational points of some connected reductive group over $\mathbb Q_p$, which we still denote by $G$.

> Are all the special maximal compact subgroups of $G$ good?

Recall that a maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$ is good if we have the Iwasawa decomposition $G = P_0G$ where $P_0$ is a minimal $\mathbb Q_p$-parabolic subgroup of $G$ (définition 4.4.1 in Bruhat-Tits' paper "groupes réductifs sur un corps local: I. Données radicielles évaluées).

Proposition 4.4.6.(i) in loc. cit. states that if a certain homomorphism $\varphi$ is of "connected type", then all special maximal compact subgroups of $G$ are good. Thus, I may also ask the question "is the $\varphi$ of loc. cit. of connected type in the context of $p$-adic unitary groups?"

Now, I have tried to unravel the definitions of $\varphi$ and of being of connected type, but I failed to get an idea of what it means and how it applies to the situation I consider. In particular, the definition of $\varphi$ itself seems to depend on the choice of an auxiliary group $\widehat{G}$ which makes me confused. I would greatly appreciate if somebody could break it down to me.